# Use django auth with WordPress

Tags: python, php, django, wordpress, single-sign-on

I want to make a website with Django as backend for most of the task, but for the frontend I want to use WordPress for page management and also to use Elementor as GUI page builder.
But problem is that I want to make a single login system for both WordPress and Django with of course Django default user table.

I have read a lot of articles about it they all somehow revolve wp-api but I don't require this in my case.

I just want to sign-in into WordPress with Django table. And also if user is logged in into Django it must be logged into WordPress with same session (I am using same domain).

Comment: What have you tried doing or at least what are you considering? There's countless ways you can approach this but most likely you'd need to implement an extension to wordpress that allows integration with django (unless someone else  already did)

Comment: The session part might be really complicated, and I think the only real safe way to do it would be to have a shared common backing store like a database

Comment: If I were to build this, after successful authentication with Django I would redirect over to a custom page on WordPress that ultimately calls [`wp_set_auth_cookie`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_auth_cookie/). You'll need to pass user information over from Django to WP and possibly create users in WP, and I'd sign and possibly encrypt the payload, and throw some nonces (shared database) and expirations into the mix. You can then optionally redirect from WP back to Django depending on your business logic

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_authenticate/

Comment: If you don't require the wp-api, then you should share what prevents you doing it differently. Why do you mention all those things that are not relevant for your use-case? I mean nice story and so on, and congratulations for your article reading progress, but how is that relevant to the question? Consider to [edit] and provide a  [mre], so your programming problem becomes more visible.

Comment: I have used django as an sso server with openid connect support and then used a basic sso plugin in WordPress. This solved my problem.